# How can I solve this Heap sort problem and represent it as an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

[image: Heapsort problem I need help with]

I need some help solving this heapsort problem. I feel like its simple but I want to see what you guys get to check my answer.!

Please check my work below! :)

[image: What I have so far]

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: My question is how can I solve this Heap sort problem and represent it as an array

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not correct, sorry.

Why your answer is wrong: You can't, in general, swap elements in a heap, because a heap has the essential invariant that the element in a given node is always greater than the elements in its child nodes (or always lesser, if it's a min-heap as opposed to a max-heap; but the heap in your problem is a max-heap). In your answer, you're taking a max-heap and swapping elements until it's a min-heap; but you're not allowed to do that, and that's not what the problem is looking for you to do.

In fact, the problem is a bit unclear — "sorting the heap" is not a standard term — but I think what it's asking you to do is the second part of [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort):

- This part of heapsort works by removing the root element from the heap (i.e., the greatest element) and putting it at the end of the array, then removing the new root element and putting it at the second-to-last position, and so on, until the heap is empty. So you should show the '23' being removed (and the '17' and '16' being bumped upward and the '1' moved over), then the '17' being removed (and the '16' and '8' being bumped upward and the '1' moved over), and so on, making sure that you always maintain a max-heap and that the last row of the heap is always perfectly filled in from left to right.
- You've correctly understood the array representation of a heap, so I won't go into that, except to note that every time you remove an element from the heap, the heap covers one fewer array-element than before; specifically, it stops covering the exact array-element that you need to put that heap-element into. So heapsort doesn't require an extra array, or anything; the heap shrinks and the sorted part of the array grows until the heap is empty and the entire array is sorted.
- Note that heapsort also has a step *before* what you're being asked to do, where the array is "heapified" to create the heap to begin with. In your problem, this has apparently already been done — you're given the heap — so you only need to worry about the second part, where you move elements out of the heap.

Alternatively, perhaps you're right that it's looking for you to convert the tree (not actually a "heap" in that case) into a min-heap. That is the "heapify" operation that's the first part of heapsort. In that case, that *does* involve swapping elements; *but* you can only swap an element with its immediate parent or child, not just arbitrary elements. (And you don't need to sort the whole thing in that case; just enough to satisfy the min-heap invariant.) But I don't *think* that this is what your problem is asking you to do.

Comment: I understand now thanks!!

Comment: @RyanMonahan if it's your answer please mark it as an answer so it could help others with the same problem.

Comment: @RyanMonahan: You're welcome!